# How to solve (plugin postcss) Error: File to import not found or unreadable: smui-theme. Material UI Svelte project

Tags: sass, material-ui, svelte, rollupjs

I am integrating [Material UI](https://sveltematerialui.com/) into a Svelte project.

I follow everything from the [documentation](https://github.com/hperrin/svelte-material-ui), but I get this error when running my project:

```
!] (plugin postcss) Error: File to import not found or unreadable: smui-theme.
node_modules/@smui/tab/_index.scss
Error: File to import not found or unreadable: smui-theme.
```

What can be the problem?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The error means that you must have a file called `_smui-theme.scss` in order to be able to compile Sass.

First make sure you have the file `_smui-theme.scss` in your project under `theme` directory.
(I usually put it in `src/theme/_smui-theme.scss`)

Then you have to add it in the `postcss` config of your rollup plugin like this:

```
import postcss from 'rollup-plugin-postcss';

export default {
    ...
    plugins: [
        svelte({
            ...
        }),

        ....

        postcss({
            extract: true,
            minimize: true,
            use: [
                ['sass', {
                    includePaths: [
                        './src/theme',     <<< ------------ HERE    
                        './node_modules'
                    ]
                }]
            ]
        }),
        ...
};
```

Make sure the `theme` directory is well included in the `postcss` plugin config like shown before.

Note: if the path is not right, you may receive the same error!